# Errors in updating/configuring amdgpu-pro driver on Ubuntu 16.04 for RX 480

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I installed the amdgpu-pro driver according to the official installation instructions found at: [AMD installation instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx).

After installation was complete, I ran:

```
sudo apt update
```

and received this message:

```
E: The repository 'file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I went to gather some more information that might help figure out what is going wrong. I ran:

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

The output was:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name: amdgpu-pro, Version: 16.30.3-315407, Architecture: amd64, Description: This package install all amdgpu-pro components.
```

If anyone could help out that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your card actually working with the driver? Try `lspci -k` and look for your card in the output (mine is usually at 01:00.0) and shows this output `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] (rev c7)`. Importantly you should also see this in the output in the same section 'kernel driver in use: amdgpu'

Also check OpenGL is using your card `glxinfo | grep -i opengl`. I'm re-installing my system at the moment so I don't have the exact output but you should see something along the line of OpenGL version 4.5 core profile and Gallium 0.4 on AMD something something

Anyway I had that same error message previously from apt `The repository 'file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Release' does not have a Release file.` but it didn't stop my card from working correctly. I think a line gets added into your sources.list for apt so you could google to see how to remove entries from that file.

Comment: yea thanks that all seems to be working. I guess it's just that release. thank you!